# I have a WinForms "button", how do I click and drag it without activating the button?

Tags: c#, winforms

My WinForm is just a 40x40 button that users can click to call for help. Everything works except when you click and drag to move the button to a different part of the screen the button activates after releasing the left mouse button (completing the "click"). Is there a way to check if the window has moved while the `mousedown` event is happening and stop the `mouseclick` event in that case?

How I am currently doing "click and drag":

```
    private void btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Left = e.X + this.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you performing this move? Dragging a standard button within a standard form does not cause the form (or button) to move. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, you're not missing anything. I'll update the question.

Comment: Right now, your code is moving the form, not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a flag to handle that:

```
private bool ignoreClick = false;

private void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    ignoreClick = true;
    btn.Left = e.X + btn.Left - mouseDownLocation.X;
    btn.Top = e.Y + btn.Top - mouseDownLocation.Y;
  }
}

private void btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  ignoreClick = false;
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!ignoreClick) {
    // do your click code...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also move the form via the button like this instead:

```
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a subclassed button, you can prevent the click event from firing if the cursor has been moved too far (which, I think, should really be the default behaviour).
This way, the actual event handlers can be kept a bit cleaner and don't have to deal with this.

```
class SpecialButton: Button
{
    private Point ClickOrigin;
    private const int ClickMaxDistance = 5;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickOrigin = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        if(Math.Abs(p.X - ClickOrigin.X) < ClickMaxDistance &&
            Math.Abs(p.Y - ClickOrigin.Y) < ClickMaxDistance)
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```